# Input NAs in a dataframe

Tags: r, na

I would like to input `NAs` in a dataframe setting a specific number of rows. Let´s suppose that I would like two rows of `NAs`

This is my input:

```
df <- "col1 col2 col3"
df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)

> ncol(df)
[1] 3
```

And below is my expected output

```
dfout <- "col1 col2 col3
          NA    NA   NA
          NA    NA   NA"
dfout <- read.table(text=dfout, header=T)

> ncol(dfout)
[1] 3

> nrow(dfout)
[1] 2
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We replicate the 'NA' 2 times i.e the nrows required, convert to `list`, replicate '3' based on the number of substrings in 'df', set the names of the 'list' with 'df' after extracting the individual elements using `scan` and convert to 'data.frame'.

```
data.frame(setNames(rep(list(rep(NA,2)),3), scan(text=df, sep='', what='')))
```

Converting the one line to small chunks for better explanation.

```
v1 <- scan(text=df, sep='', what='')#extract individual elements
nR <- 2 #specify the nrows
nC <- length(v1) #ncols based on the length of 'v1'
lst <- rep(list(rep(NA, nR)), nC) #replicate NA.
names(lst) <- v1 #set the 'names' of 'list'
data.frame(lst)  #convert to 'data.frame'
```

#### data

```
df <- "col1 col2 col3"
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
dfout <- df
# dfout[c(1,2),] <- c(NA, NA, NA) # not necessary - see comment below
dfout[c(1,2),] <- NA
dfout
#   col1 col2 col3
# 1   NA   NA   NA
# 2   NA   NA   NA
```

by setting the `dfout` row indices in the second line, you should be able to do the job.

Comment: One `NA` would suffice thanks to recycling.  `df[c(1, 2), ] <- NA `

Comment: Also `df[c(1, 2), ]` for this case